# How can i embed a youtube video using sencha

Tags: javascript, mobile, youtube, sencha-touch, extjs

I had tried the iframe for embedding youtube video in sencha inside the html tag.

```
....
html:'<iframe>Youtube URL</iframe>'
....
```

I added the above code inside the second icon of the tab bar. The second icon is a scroll view.i.e i set it to `scroll:'vertical'`

My Problem is when i add youtube video.It comes like this...
[image: Image 1]

Look.Only Part of the video is shown.

when i switch to other tab panel,the video appears as below.

[image: image2]

Any Help!!!

Answer (score 1):

I've done this using HTML inside a panel.  of course it doesn't play embedded in the sencha app.  It jumps to the youTube player.

```
html: '<div style="margin-left:12px; margin-top:20px"><h1>Syndicate Trailer</h1><p><iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ewwtznVkSxA" frameborder="0"></iframe></p><h1>Prometheus Trailer</h1><p><iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/sftuxbvGwiU" frameborder="0"></iframe></p></div>'
```

This leaves the links in the video frame which didn't suit my app so I modified to use this instead:

```
html: '<div style="margin-left:12px; margin-top:20px"><h1>Eddies Cinema Slot </h1><p><embed id=\"yt\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5a9-ORWn0fY\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"290\" height=\"260\"></embed></p></div>'
```